# merge sorted files, with minimal buffering

Tags: linux, bash, posix, zsh

I have two log files that are prefixed with a sortable timesetamp.
I'd like to see them, in order, while the processes generating the log files are still running. This is a pretty faithful simulation of the situation:

```
slow() {
    # print stdout at 30bps
    exec pv -qL 30
}
timestamp() {
    # prefix stdin with a sortable timestamp
    exec tai64n
}

# Simulate two slowly-running batch jobs:
seq 000 099 | slow | timestamp > seq.1 &
seq1=$!
seq 100 199 | slow | timestamp > seq.2 &
seq2=$!

# I'd like to see the combined output of those two logs, in timestamp-sorted order
try1() {
    # this shows me the output as soon as it's available,
    # but it's badly interleaved and not necessarily in order
    tail -f seq.1 --pid=$seq1 &
    tail -f seq.2 --pid=$seq2 &
}
try2() {
    # this gives the correct output,
    # but outputs nothing till both jobs have stopped
    sort -sm <(tail -f seq.1 --pid=$seq1) <(tail -f seq.2 --pid=$seq2)
}


try2
wait
```

Comment: Ah, you've already noted `nothing till both jobs have stopped` which sounds right to me. If you have data like `y,x,w,a,b,c,z`, you have to read it all to get the correct order. For very close data, as your timestamps are, you might be able to build a buffering system, but yikes! Great Q by the way! Good luck!

Comment: It should certainly be possible to buffer in "chunks" so that you could get near-to-realtime sorted log output (output logs once a minute or something) but you'll have to pick a window for that and your logs would dump in bulk.

Comment: The two streams are already sorted, so a system only really  needs the buffer one line from each stream. At that point it can print the lesser of the two and still guarantee well-sorted output. I can certainly write that in python, but I was hoping for an already-invented utility. I actually think `sort -m` should work this way...

Comment: This seems like it's really a bug in `sort -m`. Anyone fancy submitting a patch? :P

Answer (score 0):

The [solution using `tee`](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36344277/2) (to write the files so that the standard output still goes to the console) won't work because `tee` introduces unwanted latency and doesn't solve the problem.  Similarly, I couldn't get solutions using `tail -f -s 0.01` (which alters the polling to 100/s), and/or some kind of call like `split --filter='sort -sm'` to sort small batches.

I also don't have [`tai64n`](https://cr.yp.to/daemontools/tai64n.html), so my test code actually used this functionally identical perl code:

```
tai64n() {
  perl -MTime::HiRes=time -pe '
    printf "\@4%015x%x%n", split(/\./,time), $c; print 0 x(25-$c) . " "'
}
```

After failing to solve this with `sh` and `bash`, I exercised my standard failover, `perl`:

```
slow() {
    # print stdout at 30bps
    pv -qL 30
}

tai64n_and_tee() {
  # prefix stdin with a sortable timestamp and copy to given file
  perl -MTime::HiRes=time -e '
    $_ = shift;
    open(TEE, "> $_") or die $!;
    while (<>) {
      $_ = sprintf("\@4%015x%x%n", split(/\./,time), $c) . 0 x(25-$c) . " $_";
      print TEE $_;
      print $_;
    }
  ' "$1"
}

# Simulate two slowly-running batch jobs:
seq 000 099 | slow | tai64n_and_tee seq.1 &
seq 100 199 | slow | tai64n_and_tee seq.2 &
wait
```

This was convenient for me because I had already used `perl` for the timestamp.  I failed to do this with `perl` acting as `tai64n` and a separate `perl` call to act as `tee`, but it might work with the real `tai64n`.

Comment: If i sub your perl for `tai64n` I get no output till the processes end, and the output is not sorted.

Comment: If I instead use `tai64n` with your above bash script, the output is badly interleaved; some lines have two timestamps, some have none.

Comment: Okay, I hadn't actually called `tee` in my tests before publishing.  I see your issue and have rewritten the answer.  In the same loop, this perl code adds the time stamp _and_ copies to each given log file.  I doubt a perl approximation of `tee` will work with the real `tai64n` (probably the same reason the real `tee` doesn't work here, not that I understand that...)